# Using a non absulte path for Exec on a systemd user service

Tags: systemd, services

I've created a unit to run at user login, but when trying to start it, I get the following error:

```
/home/myUser/.config/systemd/user/myUnit.service:5: Neither a valid executable name nor an absolute path: $HOME/.local/bin/myProgram
```

This is `~/.config/systemd/user/myUnit.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some description...

[Service]
ExecStart=$HOME/.local/bin/myProgram
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Systemd wants an absolute path, obviously; but is there a way to not *hardcode* the home directory per every user, and also don't take out the binary outside the user's home?

I believe there should be one, since we are allowed to place user's units inside the user's own home...

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/794922/ . Try those answers.

Comment: Thank you, using `%h` was the solution! =)